# Javascript Color Iterator Not Working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, colors

First off, yes, I'm AWARE there's a much easier way to do this in jQuery, but I'm trying to learn how to do it by hand in Javascript to get a better understanding of the language.

I have a div that I want to slowly fade through many colors of the rainbow. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bar = document.getElementById("workbar");
    var x = 0;

    bar.onclick = change;

    function change() {
        requestAnimationFrame(color);
    }

    function color() {
        window.alert("color!");
        bar.style.background = "hsl(" + x + ", 100%, 50%);";
        if (x < 358) {
            x++;
            requestAnimationFrame(color);
        }

        else {
            x = 0;
            requestAnimationFrame(color);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm iterating through the first digit of the hsl color system, which will provide me with hundreds of color variations but not every single unnecessary color shade in the universe.

I click on it, and nothing happens. Now I know it's getting through to the color function because I put that alert box there and it went off. I also know it's looping through the color function because after you x out of the alert box another appears. So it must be a problem with the part where it assigns the color. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon

```
"hsl(" + x + ", 100%, 50%);";
                          ^
```

---

```js
(function () {

    var bar = document.getElementById("workbar"),
        x = 0;

    function color() {
        bar.style.background = "hsl(" + x + ", 100%, 50%)";
        x++; 
        if (x >= 358) {
            x = 0;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(color);
    }

    function change() {
        requestAnimationFrame(color);
    }

    bar.addEventListener("click", change, false);

}());
```

```html
<div id="workbar">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch.  It's usually the little things that screw me up.